# How to write a scenario match with a value from the header in karate mock

Tags: mocking, karate

I want to match a request with a value from the header. Let's say I have a header field as member with value 'abcd', then I want a scenario something like

Scenario: pathMatches('/getValues') && headerValue('member')

I know there is no function called headerValue but something like that I want to achieve. Then I need to def a response. There is typeContains() and acceptContains() but not to the one as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`requestHeaders`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#requestheaders) directly. Try this:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/getValues') && karate.get('requestHeaders.member[0]') == 'abcd'
```

Note that you can create re-usable functions in the `Background` to make some of this easier.

Comment: I just checked with the way you have mentioned Peter but it is not working for me.  I get below error 16:38:06.579 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - scenario skipped: pathMatches('/getValues') && karate.get('requestHeaders.member[0]') == 'abcd'

Comment: @irfanmike it does, I just checked and added a test case, see this commit: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/e22c9ffa7931c4b5ccb21b5f5cce4e2f7bd8f31b - so if you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Cool thanks Peter, i will check it and comment here